# extract text from xml tags in an XML file using apach tika parser

Tags: xml, apache-tika

I am trying to extract all the text out of various documents. 
And for that I am using Apache Tika 1.4.

```
RecursiveTikaParser parser = new RecursiveTikaParser(new AutoDetectParser());
ParseContext parseContext = new ParseContext();
parseContext.set(Parser.class, parser);
```

RecursiveTikaParser here is just a wrapper on AutoDetectParser.

Parse method for which is something like this -

```
ContentHandler content = new BodyContentHandler(-1);
Metadata metadata = new Metadata();
super.parse(stream, content, metadata, context);
System.out.println("Parsed text is " + content.toString());
```

Now, this code has to be able to handle multiple files so that's why I am using AutoDetectParser()

I noticed in my testing that given an xml file - I can only extract the text that is between the tags and not the comments, tags.

Is it possible to extract everything from the text file with my current approach ?

Answer (score 0):

Try like this

```
    Metadata metadata = new Metadata();
    stream = TikaInputStream.get(stream, null);
    String mimtType = DETECTOR.detect(stream, metadata).toString();
    Parser parser;
    if (mimtType.equalsIgnoreCase("application/xml")) {
        parser = new TXTParser();
    } else {
        parser = new AutoDetectParser();
    }

    ContentHandler content = new BodyContentHandler();
    parser.parse(stream, content, metadata, new ParseContext());
    System.out.println(content.toString());
```