# extract text from text files XML, HTML, etc, using Tika

Tags: html, xml, apache-tika, extract

Like this question, [extract text from xml tags in an XML file using apach tika parser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21175172/extract-text-from-xml-tags-in-an-xml-file-using-apach-tika-parser)

I want to extract all text from text based files, including tagged content, the tags themselves, and other text in XML/HTML elements.

I've tried XML (application/xml), and HTML (text/html) and seen that AutoDetectParser returns less than the full text content.

I've also tried YAML (text/plain), and JSON (text/plain) which do return the full text content.

I understand that I can't do XML or HTML using the AutoDetectParser. What I can't find documented is a list of what types of files would need special handling.

To get full text content (even if that means a complete 'raw' copy of the file):
1. What Mimetypes should be parsed using a TXTParser?
2. What Mimetypes should be parsed using other parsers?

Basically, I'm asking what Mimetypes does the AutoDetectParser return less than the full text content?

Thanks

**EDIT**

My use case is to be able to extract text and metadata from a wide variety of input file formats including txt, xml, html, doc(x), ppt(x), pdf, ...

Essentially, I want to be able to handle any file type Tika can handle.

I am using code like this

```
AutoDetectParser parser = new AutoDetectParser();
BodyContentHandler handler = new BodyContentHandler();
Metadata metadata = new Metadata();
ParseContext context = new ParseContext();
context.set(Parser.class, parser);

try (InputStream stream = new FileInputStream(fileToExtract)){
    parser.parse(stream, handler, metadata, context);
} catch ... {
}
```

I see the same results for XML files as the question referenced above.

What I am trying to find out is: where is it documented when the combination of AutoDetectParser and BodyContentHandler will return less than the full text of the input file.

When, or for what Mimetypes, do I need to switch the Parser and/or ContentHandler?

I don't see this information clearly documented, and I am hoping to avoid a trail and error approach.

Comment: Without your code it's pretty tough to see what you're doing wrong... The text extraction is actually based on extracting to xhtml then throwing away the tags, so there shouldn't be a difference

Comment: I am using the code from the answer to the above StackOverflow question. I am trying to get more info on what Mimetypes should use a parser other than AutoDetectParser to get full text content.
The example referenced cover XML (application/xml), what others should follow the XML pattern?

Comment: That code uses `BodyContentHandler`, which as the name suggests gets just the body part, just switch to one that gets the full content and you should be fine!

Comment: @Gagravarr, I also had that thought. It is difficult to determine 'one that gets the full content ' from the documentation. Even 'ToTextContentHandler' which was the closest I could find, ignores <script> and <style> tags.

Comment: If you don't care about indent etc, just grab a plain one off `SAXTransformerFactory`. See https://github.com/apache/tika/blob/master/tika-app/src/main/java/org/apache/tika/cli/TikaCLI.java#L1007 for one example of setting one up for nicer output

Comment: Thank you for that pointer and example. That was instructive. Unfortunately, this doesn't answer my underlying question. See edits above.

Comment: Just ask the Tika CLI or similar for the XHTML, and look at what's in the body and what isn't?

Comment: So the trial and error approach. What a pain. This info needs to be known ahead of time, before the file gets inspected.

Comment: If you want all of the content, you need to use a handler that doesn't ignore parts of the content, it's as simple as that!